# SKAdNetwork library for react-native

Tags: react-native, skadnetwork

Is there a library available for react-native which allows you to call [registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/2943654-registerappforadnetworkattributi) from the SKAdNetwork?